# What is the license for using DBAccess

Tags: ios, dbaccess

I could not find the license on their [website](http://www.db-access.org).
In what way are we allowed to use the library in our apps?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The license is MIT and it's detailed in the DBAccess.h file.  We will add a page to the website as well,  it is mentioned on the CocoaPod page as well in case that helps.

Thanks
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

Just a note to say that now the project is Open Source and available at http://sharkorm.com, still under the MIT license.  Shark is the open source equivalent of DBAccess.